# How do I call a function from a different view controller?

Tags: swift, string, function, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have what is basically a notes app, and I am trying to call a function that is in one view controller from another. How do I do this, or is there a better way I should do it?

Here's where I am trying to call the function from

```
class NoteDetailViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var funcButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func funcButTouched(sender: UIButton)
    {
     // where i want to call the function
    }
}
```

And where the function is

```
class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    // the function
    func wordCount()
    {
        var contentArr = Project.sharedInstance.content.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        for (index, element) in contentArr.enumerate()
        {
            let location = conciseArr.indexOf(element)
            if (location != nil)
            {
                contentArr[index] = inflatedArr[location!]
                afterStr = contentArr.joinWithSeparator(" ")
                Project.sharedInstance.after = afterStr
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried just creating an instance of ListTableViewController and just calling the function that way but I get an error.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking?

Comment: Can you show me your UIViewController  hierarchy ?

Comment: The order of my view controllers? It goes ListTableViewController to NoteDetailViewController

Comment: You should use delegates to do this. visit here for more info https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Comment: Base on scenario best way parent object throw call your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html).

First, declare a delegate protocol. This should be in your `NoteDetailViewController.swift` file but outside of the `class` declaration:

```
protocol NoteDetailViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func noteDetailViewControllerButtonTouched(controller: NoteDetailViewController)
}
```

Next, add a delegate property to your `NoteDetailViewController`:

```
weak var delegate: NoteDetailViewControllerDelegate?
```

Now, we use the `@IBAction` to tell the delegate, which will be the `ListTableViewController`:

```
@IBAction func funcButTouched(sender: UIButton)
{
    delegate?.noteDetailViewControllerButtonTouched(self)
}
```

Finally, back in `ListTableViewController` (assuming this controller is the one directly before a `NoteDetailViewController` is shown), conform to the protocol and use `prepareForSegue` to set the delegate to itself:

```
class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController, NoteDetailViewControllerDelegate {
    // ... more stuff ...

    // Implement the delegate protocol
    func noteDetailViewControllerButtonTouched(controller: NoteDetailViewController) {
        // Do something! The button was pressed! 
        wordCount()
    }
    // Set ourselves as delegate when we are about to show the other view controller
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let yourVC = segue.destinationViewController as? NoteDetailViewController {
            yourVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

---

You should finish with something like this:

`NoteDetailViewController.swift`:

```
class NoteDetailViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var funcButton: UIButton!
    weak var delegate: NoteDetailViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBAction func funcButTouched(sender: UIButton)
    {
        delegate?.noteDetailViewControllerButtonTouched(self)
    }
}

protocol NoteDetailViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func noteDetailViewControllerButtonTouched(controller: NoteDetailViewController)
}
```

`ListTableViewController.swift`:

```
class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController, NoteDetailViewControllerDelegate
{
    // the function
    func wordCount()
    {
        var contentArr = Project.sharedInstance.content.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        for (index, element) in contentArr.enumerate()
        {
            let location = conciseArr.indexOf(element)
            if (location != nil)
            {
                contentArr[index] = inflatedArr[location!]
                afterStr = contentArr.joinWithSeparator(" ")
                Project.sharedInstance.after = afterStr
            }
        }
    }
    // Implement the delegate protocol
    func noteDetailViewControllerButtonTouched(controller: NoteDetailViewController) {
        // Do something! The button was pressed! 
        wordCount()
    }
    // Set ourselves as delegate when we are about to show the other view controller
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let yourVC = segue.destinationViewController as? NoteDetailViewController {
            yourVC.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On the `yourVC.delegate = self` line I get the error "Cannot assign value of type 'ListTableViewController' to type 'NoteDetailViewControllerDelegate?'

Comment: @SethRodgers did you forget to change the class declaration? Check the first line.

Comment: Yep! But now when with everything working the 'Project.sharedInstance.after' does not display the afterStr. I know it gets the value but it simply doesn't display it.

Comment: @SethRodgers Try adding a call to `tableView.reloadData()` at the end

Answer (score 0):

**Just follow bellow code its very simple** :-

NoteDetailViewController.swift:

```
class NoteDetailViewController: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var funcButton: UIButton!

    var parentListTableView : ListTableViewController!
    @IBAction func funcButTouched(sender: UIButton)
    {
        parentListTableView.wordCount()

    }
}
```

ListTableViewController.swift:

```
class ListTableViewController: UITableViewController
{
    // the function
    func wordCount()
    {
        var contentArr = Project.sharedInstance.content.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        for (index, element) in contentArr.enumerate()
        {
            let location = conciseArr.indexOf(element)
            if (location != nil)
            {
                contentArr[index] = inflatedArr[location!]
                afterStr = contentArr.joinWithSeparator(" ")
                Project.sharedInstance.after = afterStr
            }
        }
    }

    // Set ourselves as delegate when we are about to show the other view controller
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let yourVC = segue.destinationViewController as? NoteDetailViewController {
            yourVC.parentListTableView = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would work, but forces the need for `wordCount` to stay public. Delegation allows each view controller to stay in control of its own functions and not allow other view controllers to abuse them.

Comment: You are right but suppose only use for one viewcontrols  then net need to use protocol thats  why I suggest this why.